# How to ignore parseErrorOccurred when using NSXMLParser to parse xml

Tags: html, objective-c, parsing, nsxmlparser

I'm now using NSXMLParser to parse html, but when meet "br" tag in html, it will throw an error for mismatch and stop to parse, because typically "/br" tag will not appear in html. So I want to ignore this mismatch error to continue parse, how to deal with it?

Comment: @stackoverflow For example, <head><body><br></body></head>. NSXMLParser will throw an error with br mismatch error info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but you might consider to do some regex correction before parsing, such as:

`$input =~ s/<br>/<br \/>/ig;`

Comment: should I do the same thing to all single tag like br?  is this the only way?

Comment: ybbaigo - It is kind of "hack" solution, as regex is not the best approach to deal with HTML/XML. Good parsers should do handle it, but if not, you can do this regex correction for any kind of tag...

Comment: I think the best way is to use kissxml but NSXMLParser.

Comment: @ybbaigo - Parser is always better solution then regex